# Change title of appendix in report class

Tags: report

I'm writting a report so I use the class 'report' and I would like to include several appendix. For this I use '\appendix'.

My problem is in the result that it gives me to the display at the level of the title of the appendix, for example:

```
A. Questionnaire.
```

And I will want to get to the display the title as follows:

```
Appendix A: Questionnaire
```

How can I do ?

EDIT

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Pour les algorithmes
% \usepackage{algorithm}
% \usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[inoutnumbered,ruled,french]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% Pour utiliser les accents
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}
%pour les informations sur un document compile en pdf et les lien externes/internes
\usepackage{hyperref}
%pour la mise en page des tableaux
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%espacement entre les lignes
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength\cftparskip{-2pt}
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{-2pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-2pt}

%police et mise en page du document 

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\textbf{\thechapter}}{14pt}{\huge\bf}

%\newpagestyle{mystyle}
%{\sethead[\thepage][][\sectiontitle]{}{}{\thepage}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{subfig}
% Bibliographie
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\Sum}{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sum}}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Intoduction}
blabla
\chapter{Experiences}
blabla
\chapter{Results}
blabla
\chapter{conclusion}
blabla
\appendix
\chapter{Questionnaire}
blabla
\chapter{Other Results}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal working example so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: What you get is not normal for `report`, you are doing something that changes the layout. We cannot know what, unless you post a minimal working example.

Comment: I don't really understant what you need but I edit with all package that I use :-/

Comment: unrelated to your question but `\newcommand{\Sum}{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sum}}` looks very wrong, it will make the entire math expression that it is use in displaystyle

Comment: by a minimal working example is meant a complete document that makes the image shown, so people can see the issue and test answers.

Comment: The document preamble is a mess. You're loading `hyperref` twice -- and both times too early... and it is not compilable

Comment: `\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\textbf{Appendix \thechapter:}}{14pt}{\huge\bfseries}` right after `\appendix`

Comment: think you @Johannes_B

Comment: why `[utf8x]` rather than the standard `[utf8]` for inputenc?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain this easily with the `apptools`  apckage, which defines the `\IfAppendix` conditional.

Unrelated: as a general rule, load `hyperref` as the last package (very few exceptions – most notably `cleveref`) and the file options of `babel` as options for the document class, so that all packages which depend on language be aware of the main language of the document. I also simplified the options of geometry: when  all margins are equal, you amy just write `margin = ...`. Also, needless to load `array` if you load `tabularx`: it loads it for you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, french]{report}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Pour les algorithmes
% \usepackage{algorithm}
% \usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[inoutnumbered,ruled,french]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% Pour utiliser les accents
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{spy, calc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}
%pour la mise en page des tableaux
\usepackage{tabularx}
%espacement entre les lignes
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength\cftparskip{-2pt}
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{-2pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-2pt}

%police et mise en page du document

\usepackage[margin=2cm,]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{apptools}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\IfAppendix{\appendixname\,\thechapter\,:\hspace{-14pt} }{\thechapter}}{14pt}{}

%\newpagestyle{mystyle}
%{\sethead[\thepage][][\sectiontitle]{}{}{\thepage}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{subfig}
% Bibliographie
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\Sum}{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\sum}}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{afterpage}
%pour les informations sur un document compile en pdf et les lien externes/internes
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
blabla
\chapter{Experiences}
blabla
\chapter{Results}
blabla
\chapter{Conclusion}
blabla
\appendix
\chapter{Questionnaire}
blabla
\chapter{Other Results}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did not knew about `apptools` package. But is it not easier to redefine corresponding macros from `report.cls`?

Comment: In general, I prefer to use macros from well-established packages, written by skilful package writers, than writing myself cryptic macros of which I do not see the side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Johannes_B is quite right that this is not normal behaviour for the "report" class.

However, I was able to run the pasted in LaTeX code and so it does represent an MWE.

I believe the problem comes in where you (or the creator of your document template) has redefined the chapter \titleformat just after the \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\textbf{\thechapter}}{14pt}{\huge\bf}

This command above instructs LaTeX to only print the chapter NUMBER and not the default text which is "Chapter 1" or such.  Since the Appendices are also just "chapters" they are also affected by this declaration and they will "lose" their default "text" - it is only logical that LaTeX will only print the "number" which in this case is an alphabetic letter since the declaration of \appendix switches from numeric to alphabetic by default.

If you want uniformity the simplest way is to remove that statement and then you will get Chapter 1, Chapter 2, and Appendix A as well.

However, if you are certain that you only want the Appendix word to appear for the appendices and no Chapters in the chapters then you can insert this line just after the \appendix statement

\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\textbf{Appendix \thechapter:}}{14pt}{\huge\bf}

This will now tell LaTeX to insert the text "Appendix" before the number/letter and I have put a colon in there as well but that you can remove or use --- to insert an "em-dash" or any preferred punctuation --- or none.

Unless you have a specific need to remove the word "Chapter" in the earlier headings, though, the cleanest and most uniform results would be to use the LaTeX defaults in which case just remove that first \titleformat{....} statement and you will be all set.

But I am biased 'cos I love the LaTeX defaults most times :-)

Comment: Couldn't you just have posted an MWE with the explanation?

Comment: I did think about that, Johannes_B, but since it was just one line that the questioner needed to insert and it was easy to explain where I just felt it would be more concise to post that - since I felt it would be helpful to explain the logic behind it as well.  I still have it in my Emacs buffer and will post it below.  Just noted that a solution has been posted so I won't.

Comment: Please mark code as such

Comment: I will do in future Christian.  The solution that was given later using \Ifappendix is far better so I will not edit my own just now.  It will probably disappear in time.

Comment: @RamaLakshmanan: No, only next time ... everytime... and you have to use the @ character in front of a user name in order to reply to a comment